# Start Internet Explorer 10 in Metro UI with Script

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

I want to create a custom tile which starts Google Mail.
I have this script to open Google Mail in IE10:

```
'File Launcher for Modern Tile Maker

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

     objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iediagcmd.exe""" & "https://mail.google.com"



'MODERN TILE MAKER FOR WINDOWS 8
'2012 KDapplications\The Windows Club
```

Google Mail will be opend in Internet Explorer but on the desktop. I want the URL to be opend in IE in the Metro UI.
What are the commandline parameters to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just pin the website to start from internet explorer instead. Start IE in Modern UI and go to Gmail, then press `Pin site` -> `Pin to start`  in the menu. This should give you the same result, in a much easier way.